# Unity's Universal Render Pipeline performance problem? (2D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, light

I never got real answer for this. I open this new empty project (total blank but with one GameObject) 
I ended up getting 2500FPS, alright? Makes sense. The moment I install URP and then you know place in the graphics asset. BAM 1100FPS. What's going on? I put lights, well FPS keeps on decreasing. Wasn't this supposed to be better than the normal standard pipeline? If I can't do this, what are the other ways to make these optimized lights? What can I do for it?

P.S. I have been using since LWRP and then recently changed to URP. It's been at least a year, I feel like I cannot make my own game using these lights and I don't know what to do with it. This is the performance loss after just installing it, think when you have to add logic? Well, that is bad. Do I look for certain settings for this?

Comment: 2500fps?? that is serious fps there,  Lots of things can make a huge difference, one I do know is the kind of skybox you use, most people are happy with 30-60fps.. now, obviously it depends what you add and how things are rendered but anything really over 60 is not that detectable by humans so...

Comment: Compare it with more objects in the scene. There might be an overhead with a better performance overall.

Comment: Well, it is. But when you have a complex scene, it doesn't work that great. Moment you add logic to yours NPC(s) and have more gameobjects - that will decrease right?

Comment: You are not alone. Follow this thread: https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-universal-render-pipeline-causing-massive-slow-down-on-2d-mobile-project.826647. I made a bunch of tests with the simplest scene setup, and my phone gets either hot, either fps drops. URP 9.0 is still private and hopefully, they will improve it. But in URP 8.1 it doesn't look really promising. Unity says URP performance is their current priority (quote from the thread).

Comment: exactly the same problem. I switch back to no pipeline and its all sorted, choose URP, boom! 10 fps. 
and its on my computer not on mobile. a very good core i5 laptop!

Answer (score 0):

If your game is running above 60FPS you are OK. you do not have to worry about performance at this stage. Add assets according to your game design, tweak your scene with lights, Unity offers my tools than can improve the performance of the game. But I suggest you do profiling after you build something concrete.

Comment: I understand, I have been using Unity for long time. I am aware but losing 1000FPS just to add the pipeline? Let alone adding lights. Any idea what to do with that? Or should I just build the game and then add the lights if necessary. 
2D Game btw.

Comment: Ok, another case. I am working on project. It runs on 22-24 FPS on my android device, using built-in rendering pipeline. I installed URP, configured it, according to manual, built app again - and voila! 16-18 FPS! Should I worry about IT?

Comment: Totally agree with author - it`s strange to get performance drop after installing URP, which is declared as best for performance.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really look at frame-rate for profiling, you need to look at the time per frame not the FPS count. Remember that the FPS is logarithmic, not linear. 2,500 FPS is a frame render of 0.4ms where 1,100 FPS is 0.9ms. The difference in this time is so small that it's almost not worth comparing. Also, target should be 60 - 144 FPS (depending on screen refresh-rate) which is a frame-time of 16.67ms - 6.9ms.

Also you need to remember that URP is forward-rendered which means the cost of each light in the scene goes up dramatically vs in Deferred in Standard.